# Is there a way to set the difficulty multiplier higher than 2x in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm currently level 67 and Survival difficulty is starting to become a little bit too easy. I believe that on Survival the difficulty multiplier is set to 2x meaning you take twice damage and deal half damage. Is it possible to increase the multiplier perhaps by console commands or by editing a config file somewhere?

Comment: Just wear less armor?

Comment: @Nelson That's certainly one way to do it. Wearing less/worse armor and using inferior weapons might work for you, but I want to be able to use the equipment of my choice. Not being forced into some specific bizzare combination to nerf my character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no known way to achieve this in game, but there is a [mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/222/?) to help you out. It allows you to fully modify all dealt and received damage.